# Bash string manipulation works differently in shell than .sh file?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, installation, environment-variables

I have a script to get and setup the latest NodeJS on my .deb system:

```
echo "Downloading, building and installing latest NodeJS"
sudo apt-get install python g++ make checkinstall
mkdir /tmp/node_build && cd $_
curl -O "http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz"
tar xf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*
NODE_VERSION="${PWD#*v}"
#NODE_VERSION=python -c "print '$PWD'.split('-')[-1][1:]"
echo "Installing NodeJS" $NODE_VERSION

./configure
sudo checkinstall -y --install=no --pkgversion NODE_VERSION
sudo dpkg -i node_$NODE_VERSION
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work; as the `echo` line outputs:

> Installing NodeJS i8/dir-where-runnning-script-from/node-v0.10.24

It does work from the shell though:

```
$ cd /tmp/node_build/node-v0.10.24 && echo "${PWD#*v}"
0.10.24
```

Comment: What doesn't work? If you do `echo "${NODE_VERSION#*v}"` you should get the same result. Though you really should use `"${NODE_VERSION##*v}"`, `"${NODE_VERSION#*v}"` only works because your path doesn't contain a `v`

Comment: My path has a `v`; see `/tmp/node_build/node-v0.10.24`. I need to get the version number out of that string, which I do with `"${PWD#*v}"`. If you look at my question, I show what output I get and what output I expected.

Comment: Sorry, I meant has a `v` before that. What do you get if you `echo $PWD` from the script after the `cd_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there another "v" in the path, like right before the "i8/"? `#*v` will remove through the *first* "v" in the variable; I'm pretty sure you want `##*v` which'll remove through the *last* "v" in the variable. (Technically, `#` removes the shortest matching prefix, and `##` removes the longest match). Thus:

```
NODE_VERSION="${PWD##*v}"
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Will accept this as answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo checkinstall -y --install=no --pkgversion "${NODE_VERSION##*v}"
```